# 30 sec rows to 1 min rows

Tags: r, excel

I have a dataset with time stamps every 30 seconds and binary along side each time stamp with either 0 meaning active and 1 meaning inactive. I want to combine two 30 second intervals into one interval marked either active or inactive based on if there is a 0 in either of the two, the new minute interval is marked 0 and if there is two 1s, the interval is marked inactive. I could probably do a macro in excel but I think it would be easier to just do it in R.

```
11:00.20 1
11:00.50 0
11:01.20 1
11:01.50 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way using `dplyr` -

```
df %>% 
  mutate(group = rep(1:n(), each = 2, length.out = n())) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise(
    timestamp = first(timestamp),
    value = case_when(
      sum(value) == 1 ~ "0",
      sum(value) == 2 ~ "inactive",
      TRUE ~ "active"
    )
  )

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  group timestamp value   
  <int> <chr>     <chr>   
1     1 11:00.20  0       
2     2 11:01.20  inactive
```

Data -

```
df <- read.table(text = "11:00.20 1
11:00.50 0
11:01.20 1
11:01.50 1", header = F, stringsAsFactors = F, col.names = c("timestamp", "value"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data:

```
df <- tibble(
   time = c("11:00.20", "11:00.50",
        "11:01.20", "11:01.50"), 
   active = c(1, 0, 1, 1))
```

I have tried `lubridate`:

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse) 
df %>% 
  mutate(
    date = hms(time), 
  ) %>% 
  group_by(hour= hour(date), minute=minute(date)) %>%  
  summarize(
    active = min(active)
  )
```

and got the following `tibble`:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   hour [1]
   hour minute active
  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1    11      0      0
2    11      1      1
```